# entity framework ctp5 get unproxied type

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-ctp5

I'm working with EF CTP5.

How can I get the unproxied type name of an entity loaded using EF.

Currently I get the proxied type.

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var unproxiedName = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(someEntity.GetType()).Name;
```

Comment: Hi Craig, is this the only way? I would rather not have to call this outside of my data layer.

Comment: It's the only *convenient* way. You could always recurse through the type hierarchy until you get a legit name.